# Run grunt tasks in Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, gruntjs, azure-webjobs

I have a couple of grunt scripts that I need to run periodically in the background for my website running on Azure. They generate files that is then made downloadable to the user.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to run Grunt.js tasks as part of a Azure WebJob. I've googled this to death but can't find anything about it. Short of spinning up a VM for this, does anybody know how I can accomplish this?

It will be easy enough to just execute it using shell, but I don't know if Azure support grunt in Webjobs or allows shell execution.

Comment: From the documentation, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#acceptablefiles it says that you can run *.js files. Otherwise may be you can use the azure scheduler : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/scheduler-get-started-portal/

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you find a solution for your problem ?

Comment: I'm actually trying it as we speak. But yes I think it looks promising.